# Git Server on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, hosting, git, cgi, share

Are there any revision control systems (git preferred) that could run on shared hosting server presumably by being launched as CGI scripts?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Do you want to host the repository or just pull the code down?  What functionality are you looking for that github.com can't provide?

Comment: I don't want to host it on github, because I want a repository for personal / private files. I want to host a repository on my server with shared hosting-- that means Ihave no terminal access.

Comment: I believe this is the solution, you are looking for.
http://serverfault.com/questions/26836/setting-up-a-git-repo-on-my-godaddy-hosting-plan

Answer (score 1):

According to its [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) git-http-backend is "a simple CGI program to serve the contents of a Git repository to Git clients accessing the repository over http:// and https:// protocols".

Comment: That requires me to install git. Shared hosting means no command line access, just SFTP and a web control panel. I need something that I can upload as CGI scripts.

Comment: You could try to upload git-http-backend binary but you need to find file compiled for your hosting OS.